# How can I determine if my TextBlock text is being trimmed?

Tags: wpf, textblock

The following textblock wraps and trims as expected. The elipsis "..." is displayed when the text is trimmed.

```
<TextBlock 
    MaxWidth="60" 
    MaxHeight="60" 
    Text="This is some long text which I would like to wrap."
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
```

I would like to display a tooltip over the text with the full text, but only if the text is trimmed. I'm not sure how to reliably determine if the "..." is being shown or not.

How do I determine if the text is being trimmed or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't done a lot of WPF lately, so I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but check out this article: [Customizing “lookful” WPF controls – Take 2](http://tranxcoder.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/customizing-lookful-wpf-controls-take-2/). It's a bit complex, but it seems to address the same question you're asking. UPDATE: The website seems gone, but you can find the article in the [archive](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://tranxcoder.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/customizing-lookful-wpf-controls-take-2/). SEE Scott Chamberlain's ANSWER WITH THE SAMPLE CODE (thanks Scott).

Comment: The algorithm mentioned in the article above is exactly what I was looking for - thanks!

Comment: @l33t I also needed the link, [here is a copy of the page](http://web.archive.org/web/20130316081653/http://tranxcoder.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/customizing-lookful-wpf-controls-take-2/) cached by the Wayback Machine.

Comment: This answer really needed to originally state how to solve the problem rather than just drop a link.

Comment: Agree with @sydan.  Don't simply link. Bad S.O. behavior. When you do, you end up at the same place we are now... a marked answer that doesn't actually have one.

Comment: The archive is now down, too. Looking at the other answer that has a copy.

Comment: @ygoe which is why I included all the details to implement it in the answer with the link ;) (also, it appears to be up again)

Comment: ...and its gone

Answer (score 32):

Because the link in Alek's answer is down, I found a [cached copy of the link](http://web.archive.org/web/20130316081653/http://tranxcoder.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/customizing-lookful-wpf-controls-take-2/) from the wayback machine. You can not download the code linked in the article, so here is a pre-assembled version of the code. There was one or two issues I ran in to while trying to make it work so this code is slightly different then the code in the examples in the article.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace TextBlockService
{
    //Based on the project from http://web.archive.org/web/20130316081653/http://tranxcoder.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/customizing-lookful-wpf-controls-take-2/
    public static class TextBlockService
    {
        static TextBlockService()
        {
            // Register for the SizeChanged event on all TextBlocks, even if the event was handled.
            EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(
                typeof(TextBlock),
                FrameworkElement.SizeChangedEvent,
                new SizeChangedEventHandler(OnTextBlockSizeChanged),
                true);
        }


        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey IsTextTrimmedKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly("IsTextTrimmed", 
            typeof(bool), 
            typeof(TextBlockService), 
            new PropertyMetadata(false));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTextTrimmedProperty = IsTextTrimmedKey.DependencyProperty;

        [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(TextBlock))]
        public static Boolean GetIsTextTrimmed(TextBlock target)
        {
            return (Boolean)target.GetValue(IsTextTrimmedProperty);
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty AutomaticToolTipEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "AutomaticToolTipEnabled",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(TextBlockService),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));

        [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(DependencyObject))]
        public static Boolean GetAutomaticToolTipEnabled(DependencyObject element)
        {
            if (null == element)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
            }
            return (bool)element.GetValue(AutomaticToolTipEnabledProperty);
        }

        public static void SetAutomaticToolTipEnabled(DependencyObject element, bool value)
        {
            if (null == element)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
            }
            element.SetValue(AutomaticToolTipEnabledProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnTextBlockSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TriggerTextRecalculation(sender);
        }

        private static void TriggerTextRecalculation(object sender)
        {
            var textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
            if (null == textBlock)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (TextTrimming.None == textBlock.TextTrimming)
            {
                textBlock.SetValue(IsTextTrimmedKey, false);
            }
            else
            {
                //If this function is called before databinding has finished the tooltip will never show.
                //This invoke defers the calculation of the text trimming till after all current pending databinding
                //has completed.
                var isTextTrimmed = textBlock.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => CalculateIsTextTrimmed(textBlock), DispatcherPriority.DataBind);
                textBlock.SetValue(IsTextTrimmedKey, isTextTrimmed);
            }
        }

        private static bool CalculateIsTextTrimmed(TextBlock textBlock)
        {
            if (!textBlock.IsArrangeValid)
            {
                return GetIsTextTrimmed(textBlock);
            }

            Typeface typeface = new Typeface(
                textBlock.FontFamily,
                textBlock.FontStyle,
                textBlock.FontWeight,
                textBlock.FontStretch);

            // FormattedText is used to measure the whole width of the text held up by TextBlock container
            FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(
                textBlock.Text,
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture,
                textBlock.FlowDirection,
                typeface,
                textBlock.FontSize,
                textBlock.Foreground);

            formattedText.MaxTextWidth = textBlock.ActualWidth;

            // When the maximum text width of the FormattedText instance is set to the actual
            // width of the textBlock, if the textBlock is being trimmed to fit then the formatted
            // text will report a larger height than the textBlock. Should work whether the
            // textBlock is single or multi-line.
            // The "formattedText.MinWidth > formattedText.MaxTextWidth" check detects if any 
            // single line is too long to fit within the text area, this can only happen if there is a 
            // long span of text with no spaces.
            return (formattedText.Height > textBlock.ActualHeight || formattedText.MinWidth > formattedText.MaxTextWidth);
        }

    }
}
```

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:tbs="clr-namespace:TextBlockService">
    <!--
    Rather than forcing *all* TextBlocks to adopt TextBlockService styles,
    using x:Key allows a more friendly opt-in model.
    -->

    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="TextBlockService">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="tbs:TextBlockService.AutomaticToolTipEnabled" Value="True" />
                    <Condition Property="tbs:TextBlockService.IsTextTrimmed" Value="True"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=Text}" />
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Good ups using the Wayback Machine like that. I keep forgetting that thing is out there.

Comment: It's already 'Opt-In' because you have to enable it with `AutomaticToolTipEnabled`. (In response to the code comment `Rather than forcing *all* TextBlocks to adopt TextBlockService styles,
    using x:Key allows a more friendly opt-in model.
`)

Comment: @KellyElton I did not want to put unnecessary triggers on every TextBlock in the window. You could just have it apply to every text box if you find it does not cause any overhead. The app this was written for was a data entry app with a table with editable cells, it added up to a few hundred text boxes.

Comment: Don't know why, `formattedText.Height` is always 0.04 bigger than `textBlock.ActualHeight` in each line. In other words, `formattedText.Height - textBlock.ActualHeight` == 0.04 in single line, for 2 lines, it's 0.08.

Answer (score 5):

The solution above didn't work for me if the TextBlock is part of a ListBoxItem DataTemplate.
I propose another solution:

```
public class MyTextBlock : System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock
{

    protected override void OnToolTipOpening(WinControls.ToolTipEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextTrimming != TextTrimming.None)
        {
            e.Handled = !IsTextTrimmed(); 
        }
    }

    private bool IsTextTrimmed()
    {
        Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
        return ActualWidth < DesiredSize.Width;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
  <MyTextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" ToolTip="{Binding Text}" />
```

Comment: This is a nice clean solution.  However it didn't work for me: my TextBlock is being trimmed (I see the ellipsis), but my DesiredSize.Width equals ActualWidth.

Comment: Did you consider the margin and padding of TextBlock?

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on bidy's answer. This will create a TextBlock that only shows the tooltip when not all text is shown. The tooltip will be resized to the contents (as opposed to the default tooltip which will remain a one-line box with the text cut off).

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyComponents
{
    public class CustomTextBlock : TextBlock
    {
        protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            // we want a tooltip that resizes to the contents -- a textblock with TextWrapping.Wrap will do that
            var toolTipTextBlock = new TextBlock();
            toolTipTextBlock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
            // bind the tooltip text to the current textblock Text binding
            var binding = GetBindingExpression(TextProperty);
            if (binding != null)
            {
                toolTipTextBlock.SetBinding(TextProperty, binding.ParentBinding);
            }

            var toolTipPanel = new StackPanel();
            toolTipPanel.Children.Add(toolTipTextBlock);
            ToolTip = toolTipPanel;

            base.OnInitialized(e);
        }

        protected override void OnToolTipOpening(ToolTipEventArgs e)
        {
            if (TextTrimming != TextTrimming.None)
            {
                e.Handled = !IsTextTrimmed();
            }
        }

        private bool IsTextTrimmed()
        {
            Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
            return ActualWidth < DesiredSize.Width;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML usage:

```
    <Window ...
        xmlns:components="clr-namespace:MyComponents"
     ... >
    
    <components:CustomTextBlock Text="{Binding Details}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a small issue using Alex answer and had to change my logic a bit to clarify if the text in the text block was being trimmed.

```
var formattedText = new FormattedText(
            Text, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection, typeface, FontSize,
            Foreground, VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi( this ).PixelsPerDip ) { MaxTextWidth = ActualWidth };
        //Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));

 return ( Math.Floor(formattedText.Height ) > ActualHeight || Math.Floor( formattedText.MinWidth ) > ActualWidth;
```

This works perfectly for me.

I defined a user control that was a TextBlock with ellipsis enabled. Then I defined 2 functions for OnMouseUp and OnMouseDown, so that when the user clicked on the textblock that had overflow it would display a tooltip with the full value.

This is the OnMouseDown function

```
private void TextBlockWithToolTipView_OnMouseDown(
        object sender,
        MouseButtonEventArgs e )
    {
        var typeface = new Typeface(
            FontFamily,
            FontStyle,
            FontWeight,
            FontStretch);

        var formattedText = new FormattedText(
            Text, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection, typeface, FontSize,
            Foreground, VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi( this ).PixelsPerDip ) { MaxTextWidth = ActualWidth };

        if (Math.Floor(formattedText.Height) > ActualHeight || Math.Floor(formattedText.MinWidth) > ActualWidth )
        {
            if( ToolTip is ToolTip tt )

            {
                {
                    if( tt.PlacementTarget == null )
                    {
                        tt.PlacementTarget = this;
                    }

                    tt.IsOpen = true;
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this was the Xaml bit

```
<TextBlock 
         ToolTipService.IsEnabled="True"
         MouseDown="TextBlockWithToolTipView_OnMouseDown"
         MouseLeave="TextBlockWithToolTipView_OnMouseLeave"   
         TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
         TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
<TextBlock.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip 
            DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=OneWay }"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </ToolTip>
    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```