# Show Tooltip when text is being trimmed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tooltip, texttrimming

```
  <TextBlock Width="100" Text="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis">
     <TextBlock.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}">
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </ToolTip>
     </TextBlock.ToolTip>
  </TextBlock>
```

How can I show the `ToolTip` only when the text is trimmed?  Like the windows desktp shortcut icons.

Answer (score 20):

Working off of Eyjafj...whatever's idea, I arrived at a working, mostly declarative solution that at least doesn't require a custom control. The first hurdle to overcome is getting at the TextBlock. Because the ToolTip is rendered outside of the visual tree, you can't use a RelativeSource binding or ElementName to get at the TextBlock. Luckily, the ToolTip class provides a reference to its related element via the PlacementTarget property. So you can bind the ToolTip's Visibility property to the ToolTip itself and use its PlacementTarget property to access properties of the TextBlock:

```
<ToolTip Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget, Converter={StaticResource trimmedVisibilityConverter}}">
```

The next step is using a converter to look at the TextBlock we've bound to to determine if the ToolTip should be visible or not. You can do this using the ActualWidth and the DesiredSize. ActualWidth is exactly what it sounds like; the width your TextBlock has been rendered to on the screen. DesiredSize is the width your TextBlock would prefer to be. The only problem is, DesiredSize seems to take the TextTrimming into account and does not give you the width of the full, untrimmed text. To solve this, we can re-call the Measure method passing Double.Positive infinity to, in effect, ask how wide the TextBlock would be if it its width were not constrained. This updates the DesiredSize property and then we can do the comparison:

```
textBlock.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));

if (((FrameworkElement)value).ActualWidth < ((FrameworkElement)value).DesiredSize.Width)
    return Visibility.Visible;
```

This approach is actually illustrated [here as an attached behavior](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2011/01/31/automatically-showing-tooltips-on-a-trimmed-textblock-silverlight-wpf.html)  if you want to apply it automatically to TextBlocks or don't want to waste resources on creating ToolTips that will always be invisible. Here is the full code for my example:

The Converter:

```
public class TrimmedTextBlockVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return Visibility.Collapsed;

        FrameworkElement textBlock = (FrameworkElement)value;

        textBlock.Measure(new System.Windows.Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));

        if (((FrameworkElement)value).ActualWidth < ((FrameworkElement)value).DesiredSize.Width)
            return Visibility.Visible;
        else
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:TrimmedTextBlockVisibilityConverter x:Key="trimmedVisibilityConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>

....

<TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{Binding SomeTextProperty}">
    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget, Converter={StaticResource trimmedVisibilityConverter}}">
            <ToolTip.Content>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeTextProperty}"/>
            </ToolTip.Content>
        </ToolTip>
    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: This works great.  The links in the accepted answer are dead, but I think the code is reproduced in this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041820/how-can-i-determine-if-my-textblock-text-is-being-trimmed  However, that seems like a lot of code and this converter solution worked for me.

Comment: Glad it helped! For reference, in case the link in my answer ever dies, it linked to _AUTOMATICALLY SHOWING TOOLTIPS ON A TRIMMED TEXTBLOCK (SILVERLIGHT + WPF)_ by Colin Eberhardt

Comment: This method is very unprecise. For some texts it works well, but other texts already get a tool tip if there's up to 8 pixels additional free space. Seems to depend on the characters in the text.

Comment: I found a **better trimming detection** and incorporated it in the complete class in my answer.

Comment: @ygoe I haven't noticed a problem with this yet. Can you please describe what you found is wrong with this solution that yours remedies (i.e. why yours is better)? This will help readers decide which answer to use (and may help me avoid running into the same problem ;)

Comment: As I already described, your solution will show a ToolTip when the TextBlock text is still completely visible, not trimmed. And it does that unpredictable. Some texts will show a ToolTip while there are 8 more pixels to shrink before the text is trimmed, some are better, so there can't be some fixed correction offset.

Comment: The other solution uses a different text measuring which seems to work precise. I don't know why that is, but it works. The other solution uses `FormattedText` directly, without all the control layout overhead around it. Also, my class wraps it all for really simple use. No need for defining converters and lengthy ToolTip definitions, just one attached property.

Answer (score 13):

Based on ideas on this page and with additional algorithmic corrections from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25436070) I made this very portable class that can be used very easily. Its purpose is to enable trimming and show a ToolTip over the TextBlock when the text is trimmed, like it is known from many applications.

The trimming detection has proven to be precise in my application. The tool tip is shown exactly when the trimming ellipsis is shown.

#### XAML usage

```
<!-- xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:Unclassified.UI" -->
<TextBlock Text="Demo" ui:TextBlockAutoToolTip.Enabled="True"/>
```

#### C# usage

```
var textBlock = new TextBlock { Text = "Demo" };
TextBlockAutoToolTip.SetEnabled(textBlock, true);
```

#### The complete class

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Unclassified.UI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Shows a ToolTip over a TextBlock when its text is trimmed.
    /// </summary>
    public class TextBlockAutoToolTip
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The Enabled attached property.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty EnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Enabled",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(TextBlockAutoToolTip),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnAutoToolTipEnabledChanged)));

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the Enabled attached property on a TextBlock control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dependencyObject">The TextBlock control.</param>
        /// <param name="enabled">The value.</param>
        public static void SetEnabled(DependencyObject dependencyObject, bool enabled)
        {
            dependencyObject.SetValue(EnabledProperty, enabled);
        }

        private static readonly TrimmedTextBlockVisibilityConverter ttbvc = new TrimmedTextBlockVisibilityConverter();

        private static void OnAutoToolTipEnabledChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            TextBlock textBlock = dependencyObject as TextBlock;
            if (textBlock != null)
            {
                bool enabled = (bool)args.NewValue;
                if (enabled)
                {
                    var toolTip = new ToolTip
                    {
                        Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Relative,
                        VerticalOffset = -3,
                        HorizontalOffset = -5,
                        Padding = new Thickness(4, 2, 4, 2),
                        Background = Brushes.White
                    };
                    toolTip.SetBinding(UIElement.VisibilityProperty, new System.Windows.Data.Binding
                    {
                        RelativeSource = new System.Windows.Data.RelativeSource(System.Windows.Data.RelativeSourceMode.Self),
                        Path = new PropertyPath("PlacementTarget"),
                        Converter = ttbvc
                    });
                    toolTip.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, new System.Windows.Data.Binding
                    {
                        RelativeSource = new System.Windows.Data.RelativeSource(System.Windows.Data.RelativeSourceMode.Self),
                        Path = new PropertyPath("PlacementTarget.Text")
                    });
                    toolTip.SetBinding(Control.ForegroundProperty, new System.Windows.Data.Binding
                    {
                        RelativeSource = new System.Windows.Data.RelativeSource(System.Windows.Data.RelativeSourceMode.Self),
                        Path = new PropertyPath("PlacementTarget.Foreground")
                    });
                    textBlock.ToolTip = toolTip;
                    textBlock.TextTrimming = TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis;
                }
            }
        }

        private class TrimmedTextBlockVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            // Source 1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21863054
            // Source 2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25436070

            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                var textBlock = value as TextBlock;
                if (textBlock == null)
                    return Visibility.Collapsed;

                Typeface typeface = new Typeface(
                    textBlock.FontFamily,
                    textBlock.FontStyle,
                    textBlock.FontWeight,
                    textBlock.FontStretch);

                // FormattedText is used to measure the whole width of the text held up by TextBlock container
                FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(
                    textBlock.Text,
                    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture,
                    textBlock.FlowDirection,
                    typeface,
                    textBlock.FontSize,
                    textBlock.Foreground,
                    VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(textBlock).PixelsPerDip);

                formattedText.MaxTextWidth = textBlock.ActualWidth;

                // When the maximum text width of the FormattedText instance is set to the actual
                // width of the textBlock, if the textBlock is being trimmed to fit then the formatted
                // text will report a larger height than the textBlock. Should work whether the
                // textBlock is single or multi-line.
                // The width check detects if any single line is too long to fit within the text area,
                // this can only happen if there is a long span of text with no spaces.
                bool isTrimmed = formattedText.Height > textBlock.ActualHeight ||
                    formattedText.MinWidth > formattedText.MaxTextWidth;

                return isTrimmed ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer would be great for reuse except for the fact that you are essentially styling the tooltip (ex Background = Brushes.White). Why is that stuff included in the answer?

Comment: @Skrymsli I'm not sure anymore why that is there. Might it be that the tooltip is displayed directly over the TextBlock text instead of somewhere offset or around the mouse cursor? So considering that most TextBlocks are black-on-white, this should lead to a ToolTip that looks just like the TextBlock itself. Otherwise, you're free to style the ToolTip as you wish, or even try to adapt to the actual appearance of the TextBlock. Also, unfortunately, exact paddings tend to change over time with newer versions of Windows and accompanying WPF themes.

Comment: @ygoe But it's easy to update you example to do not use styling. Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 12):

I found the simplest solution to extend TextBlock and compare text lengths to determine whether to show tooltip, i.e.,

```
public class ToolTipTextBlock : TextBlock
   {
      protected override void OnToolTipOpening(ToolTipEventArgs e)
      {
         if (TextTrimming != TextTrimming.None)
         {
           e.Handled = !IsTextTrimmed();
         }
      }

      private bool IsTextTrimmed()
      {
         var typeface = new Typeface(FontFamily, FontStyle, FontWeight, FontStretch);
         var formattedText = new FormattedText(Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection, typeface, FontSize, Foreground);
         return formattedText.Width > ActualWidth;
      }
   }
```

Then simply use this custom text block in xaml as follows:

```
<local:ToolTipTextBlock Text="This is some text that I'd like to show tooltip for!"
    TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
    ToolTip="{Binding Text,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    MaxWidth="10"/>
```

Comment: I like this solution, but modified slightly to have IsTextTrimmed calculated by calling this.Measure(...) and comparing this.DesiredSize.Width with this.ActualWidth

Answer (score 7):

Behaviors are love, behaviors are life.

```
public class TextBlockAutoToolTipBehavior : Behavior<TextBlock>
{
    private ToolTip _toolTip;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        _toolTip = new ToolTip
        {
            Placement = PlacementMode.Relative,
            VerticalOffset = 0,
            HorizontalOffset = 0
        };

        ToolTipService.SetShowDuration(_toolTip, int.MaxValue);

        _toolTip.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, new Binding
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath("Text"),
            Source = AssociatedObject
        });

        AssociatedObject.TextTrimming = TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis;
        AssociatedObject.AddValueChanged(TextBlock.TextProperty, TextBlockOnTextChanged);
        AssociatedObject.SizeChanged += AssociatedObjectOnSizeChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.RemoveValueChanged(TextBlock.TextProperty, TextBlockOnTextChanged);
        AssociatedObject.SizeChanged -= AssociatedObjectOnSizeChanged;
    }

    private void AssociatedObjectOnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs sizeChangedEventArgs)
    {
        CheckToolTipVisibility();
    }

    private void TextBlockOnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        CheckToolTipVisibility();
    }

    private void CheckToolTipVisibility()
    {
        if (AssociatedObject.ActualWidth == 0)
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                new Action(
                    () => AssociatedObject.ToolTip = CalculateIsTextTrimmed(AssociatedObject) ? _toolTip : null),
                DispatcherPriority.Loaded);
        else
            AssociatedObject.ToolTip = CalculateIsTextTrimmed(AssociatedObject) ? _toolTip : null;
    }

    //Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041820/how-can-i-determine-if-my-textblock-text-is-being-trimmed
    private static bool CalculateIsTextTrimmed(TextBlock textBlock)
    {
        Typeface typeface = new Typeface(
            textBlock.FontFamily,
            textBlock.FontStyle,
            textBlock.FontWeight,
            textBlock.FontStretch);

        // FormattedText is used to measure the whole width of the text held up by TextBlock container
        FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(
            textBlock.Text,
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture,
            textBlock.FlowDirection,
            typeface,
            textBlock.FontSize,
            textBlock.Foreground) {MaxTextWidth = textBlock.ActualWidth};


        // When the maximum text width of the FormattedText instance is set to the actual
        // width of the textBlock, if the textBlock is being trimmed to fit then the formatted
        // text will report a larger height than the textBlock. Should work whether the
        // textBlock is single or multi-line.
        // The width check detects if any single line is too long to fit within the text area, 
        // this can only happen if there is a long span of text with no spaces.
        return (formattedText.Height > textBlock.ActualHeight || formattedText.MinWidth > formattedText.MaxTextWidth);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:behavior="clr-namespace:MyWpfApplication.Behavior"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behavior:TextBlockAutoToolTipBehavior />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBlock>
</Window>
```

The needed extension methods:

```
public static class UITools
{
    public static void AddValueChanged<T>(this T obj, DependencyProperty property, EventHandler handler)
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var desc = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(property, typeof (T));
        desc.AddValueChanged(obj, handler);
    }

    public static void RemoveValueChanged<T>(this T obj, DependencyProperty property, EventHandler handler)
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var desc = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(property, typeof (T));
        desc.RemoveValueChanged(obj, handler);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can create a converter that compares between the `ActualWidth` of `textblock` and it's `DesiredSize.Width`, and return `Visibility`.

Answer (score 2):

Posted an alternative answer with attached property [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32655171/3009574), which I think is nicer than using a converter or a derived TextBlock control.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32655171/3009574) from @pogosoma but with the `CalculateIsTextTrimmed` function from @snicker which is perfect

```c#
private static void SetTooltipBasedOnTrimmingState(TextBlock tb)
{
    Typeface typeface = new Typeface(tb.FontFamily, tb.FontStyle, tb.FontWeight, tb.FontStretch);

    FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(tb.Text, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, tb.FlowDirection, typeface, tb.FontSize, tb.Foreground)
        { MaxTextWidth = tb.ActualWidth };

    bool isTextTrimmed = (formattedText.Height > tb.ActualHeight || formattedText.MinWidth > formattedText.MaxTextWidth);
    ToolTipService.SetToolTip(tb, isTextTrimmed ? tb.ToolTip : null);
}
```