# WPF Custom TextTrimming

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, trim

I need to do a special text trimming. Lets say that my string is: `abcd`

The default trimming would give me this: `ab...`

But I need it to be. `a..d`

Any idea how to implement it?

currnently I'm using

```
<TextBlock Text="abcdLongWord" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
```

Comment: What is the criteria for the text to be trimmed? You want only the first or last character?

Comment: ZombieHunter - I would like that the number of characters that are displayed would be configurable, but for simplifying we can start with only one character

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1041820/413032

Comment: I found such a function: http://vt-studio.co.uk/wp/?p=32

Comment: What is the purpose of the XML in your question? The string you want to trim is just a simple string, right? As in "_show only first and last letter if the string is longer than X_", am I correct?

Comment: Arvo - it seems like you are the winner, plaese make an asnwer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this concern in the past and wrote my own converter to handle the process of Kearning.

Converter Class

```
internal class KearningConverter : IValueConverter {

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        string result = value.ToString();

        try {
            int length = int.Parse(parameter.ToString());

            if (result.Length > length) {
                result = result.Substring(0, length) + "...";
            }
        } catch {
            result += "...";
        }
        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Xaml Markup

```
xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:project.converters;assembly=project"

<Window.Resources>
<conv:KearningConverter x:Key="kearnConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=AttributeName, Converter={StaticResource kearnConverter}, ConverterParameter=3}"/>
```

This way you can have multiple implementations of the kearning based on different requirements depening on the layout of your UI.

Comment: And now the funny part is to calculate ConverterParameter value dynamically. And what if TextBlock size is changed? We should trim in this case too, isn\`t it?

Answer (score -3):

Not tested this but depending on what you actually need:

```
string test = "abcdefghij";
  int nCharNum = test.Length();
  test.Remove(2, nCharNum - 1); // this will get you "aj"
  //or
  test.Remove(2, 3); // this will result in "adefg..."
  //or
  test.Remove(2, nCharNum - 1);
  test.Insert(2, "..") // this will get you "a..j"
```

Hope this helps. (Indexes may need some correction)

Comment: Thanks, but what you suggested is not textTrimming it is string manipulation, I need the text to trimm depends on the ui element width and not by hardcoded decision.

Comment: Do you want to replace inside characters when some textox is smaller then some value? Is that right?

Comment: @Erez: Where is that specified in your original question? You can't expect a "correct" answer with an imprecise question, and an answer certainly should not be voted down if it does in fact answer the written question.

Comment: I think the question is very precise.